# Cropping video in HandBrake more than 952 pixels from right

Tags: handbrake

Good day!
I have a side-by-side 1080p 3D video file (mkv). i want to crop the right image to make it non-3D. so i must cut 960 pixels from right and then adjust the aspect. but the problem is, that HandBrake doesn't allow me to  choose the value for cropping more then 952 pixels. so there stays 8 pix. line. how can i choose the value more than 952?
(Ubuntu 14.04)
Thanks

Comment: Could you crop twice?

Comment: yes, but that is not normal. i will loose the quality even more

Comment: Yeah, thought so :(. That's why I did not put it as an answer :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem solved through updating to the latest version